# Create memory index with Elasticsearch.net

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-net

I try to create memory index with following code but it creates regular index.
Any idea?

```
    var node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node);
    var client = new Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClient(settings);
    var js = JsonConvert.SerializeObject("{settings: { index.store.type: memory}");
    var index = client.IndicesCreate("sampleIndex", js);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second argument to the `IndicesCreate` method call is not correct. See the code below for a better way to achieve it. The first three lines are the same. In the fourth one, we properly create the settings for the index.

```
            _body = new {
                settings = new {
                    index = new {
                        store = new {
                            type = "memory"
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            var index = client.IndicesCreate("sampleIndex", _body);
```